# application closes after closing interstitial ad

Tags: android, admob

According to the doc: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/advanced

I am requesting from activity,

```
interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
interstitial.setAdListener(this);
```

And show the interstitial when it is received in the callback

```
 @Override
  public void onReceiveAd(Ad ad) {
    Log.d("OK", "Received ad");
    if (ad == interstitial) {
      interstitial.show();
    }
  }
```

But I've got a lot of comments, about when advert is closing by user, application closes and they must start it over. I'm not using `finish()` in `onResume` or `onStop` only in `onBackPressed`. Moreover Im using Facebook SDK in this acitivity and there is `onActivityResult`. When I testing my app on Motorola RAZR and Nexus 7 everything is ok.

Comment: can you post Cat Log or from developer console post app crash info , or my guess is when user closed the activity `Ad` still running try to add  `if (ad != null && ad == interstitial)` then show the add if ad not null or activity context not null , because if context is null the add will crash the application for no activity

Answer (score 8):

There is an attribute in your AndroidManifest.xml file, like **android:noHistory="true"** You must delete this. it solves the problem

Comment: It works for me, but the problem is I need this option ( android:noHistory="true" ) too :( so any other solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't show an interstitial when it is received, that results in a very poor user experience. Load it early and show it (if you have one) at a natural break in your app.

And there is no need to explicitly call #finish() when the back key is pressed. Android handles that for you by default.

I suspect your App closing is being caused by your onBackPressed behaviour. Remove it and I suspect it will fix itself.

Comment: Worse thing is in my devices eveything is okay, I can't even debug this. Thats way I post here

Comment: Add debug into the main Activity methods and find out what is happening. It sounds like you are explicitly calling Activity#finish() during onBackPressed, which will end your Activity (and your app if that is the only Activity in the Task stack)

Answer (score 1):

When you run *interstitial.show();* it also runs *onPause()* in the calling activity.
I also had the same problem and I had *finish()* inside the *onPause()* method.
I just removed *finish()* from the *onPause()* method and the the interstitial no longer closes the calling activity.